# Will Froala work with CollectionFS?

Tags: meteor, froala

Will the file/image tools in the Froala WYSIWYG Editor work with CollectionFS in my MeteorJS app.  Would love an example.

Comment: If you add an image, it appears to upload it to an S3 bucket. In order to change that you'll need to purchase a license that gives you the source code :)

Comment: The full code for Froala is available free if you want to play with it.  You just pay if you are using it on a commercial site.  My issue is that Froala either uses S3 or standard HTTP for upload.  But I want to use CollectionFS.

Comment: This tutorial was helpful.  Seems all the WYSIWYG Editor expect REST API for upload which Meteor doesn't support.

Comment: https://www.codetutorial.io/meteor-server-file-upload/